# Programmatically created CardView doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-cardview

So, I've made a program that automatically creates CardViewes to store Date and Name of Birthdays in them and add them to the Relative Layout in my Main Activity via this Guide: https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-how-to-create-cardview.html. I had many many errors and fixed all of them until now I just don't have an error Message to work with. As the title might tell, the CardViews just won't appear on my Main Activity. I would be very glad if someone could help me out with this. By the way, I'm pretty new to coding and don't have much experience so that might also be the problem.

Main Activity Java:

```
package com.myuserwithoutme.birthdayremember;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.myuserwithoutme.birthdayremember.CreateActivity.*;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private Context mContext;
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
Boolean pressed = false;
String mEditText1;
String mEditText2;

/
private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. "
        + "To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in res/values/strings.xml with your own ad unit ID.";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);


    AdView adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


    Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    FloatingActionButton fab1 = findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent createIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CreateActivity.class);
            startActivity(createIntent);
        }
    });




    Intent newcard = getIntent();
    for (int x = 1; x <= 0; x++) {
        if (newcard != null) {
            pressed = newcard.getExtras().getBoolean("card");
        }
    }
    Intent strings = getIntent();
    for (int x = 1; x <= 0; x++) {
        if (strings != null) {
            mEditText1 = strings.getExtras().getString("Name");
            mEditText2 = strings.getExtras().getString("Date");
        }
    }


        if (pressed != false) {
            CardView card = new CardView(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            card.setLayoutParams(params);
            card.setRadius(9);
            card.setContentPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);

            card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d3e8e7"));
            card.setMaxCardElevation(15);
            card.setCardElevation(9);
            TextView text = new TextView(mContext);
            text.setLayoutParams(params);
            text.setText(mEditText1 + "\n" + mEditText2);
            text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30);
            text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#308985"));

            card.addView(text);
            mRelativeLayout.addView(card);
        }




}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Xml Main Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24px"
    ads:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    ads:rippleColor="@android:color/background_light" />
```

Thanks for the help

EDIT:

Second Activity:

```
package com.myuserwithoutme.birthdayremember;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mEditText1;
private EditText mEditText2;
private String name;
private String date;

public boolean newcard;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);



    mEditText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mEditText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2 );
    name = mEditText1.getText().toString();
    date = mEditText2.getText().toString();


    final Intent newcard = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    FloatingActionButton fab2 = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);


            newcard.putExtra("card", true);

            Intent strings = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            strings.putExtra("Name", name);
            strings.putExtra("Date", date);
            startActivity(strings);



        }
    });

}
}
```

Second Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_save_24px"
    ads:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    ads:rippleColor="@android:color/background_light" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="DD/MM/YYYY"
    android:inputType="date" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="Gib die Daten der Person ein" />
```

Comment: Log and check if pressed != false... that might be the problem.

Comment: did you check if `mEditText1` and `mEditText2` actually contain non-empty values?

Comment: upload your other activity where you are getting the intent from

Comment: I filled mEditText1 and mEditText2 with a String manual but it didnt work. And i dont know how to log and check, i only know logcat but that only shows broken pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start the activity with `startActivityForResult` and not `startActivity` and this activity will return result values to MainActivity and not extras:  
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

What are you doing with these loops:

```
Intent newcard = getIntent();
for (int x = 1; x <= 0; x++) {
    if (newcard != null) {
        pressed = newcard.getExtras().getBoolean("card");
    }
}
Intent strings = getIntent();
for (int x = 1; x <= 0; x++) {
    if (strings != null) {
        mEditText1 = strings.getExtras().getString("Name");
        mEditText2 = strings.getExtras().getString("Date");
    }
}
```

They are not executed since the starting value is `x = 1` and it will never be `x <= 0`.  
Maybe try without the loops:

```
Intent newcard = getIntent();
if (newcard != null) {
    pressed = newcard.getExtras().getBoolean("card");
}

Intent strings = getIntent();
if (strings != null) {
    mEditText1 = strings.getExtras().getString("Name");
    mEditText2 = strings.getExtras().getString("Date");
}
```

Comment: isnt <= bigger then? so 1 is always bigger then 0

Comment: No it is less or equal than

Comment: @MyUserWithoutMe if you change it to >= though you will get an infinite  loop

Comment: Actually why is the loop for? If he is trying to get more thant one value from the intent, he could be using a list. And why getting two intents? wouldn't be enough to create just one

Comment: @SoonSantos I don't know

Comment: if i dont use that i always get a NullPointerException

Comment: @MyUserWithoutMe if you use the loops then you do nothing

Comment: @MyUserWithoutMe What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In my other activity you can enter name and date of a birthday and then the code should transfer that info to the main activity which should put that info in a cardview and display it

Comment: @MyUserWithoutMe this other activity was opened by MainActivity?

Comment: startActivity(createIntent);   this?

Comment: @MyUserWithoutMe this other activity cannot pass extra values to MainActivity. See my edited answer

Comment: Thanks, but now this happens when trying to build the app: error: no suitable method found for startActivityForResult(Intent)
method Activity.startActivityForResult(Intent,int) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: @MyUserWithoutMe in my answer I include a link. Read it to understand how to use startActivityForResult

Comment: I did that, but its marking the data thing red and it dosnt recognise the startactivityforresult, it wants me to add a method body

Comment: startActivityForResult is always recognizable in your activity but it requires 2 parameters: the intent and the requestCode

Answer (score 0):

So, I will try to help. As it was mentioned in the comment, probably your code is not reaching the part it is creating the card, it means pressed is never true.

Since I do not have the code of your other activity, I would guess you can get rid of the problem by deleting this loop that does not seem

**First Activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        pressed = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("card");
        mEditText1 = intent.getExtras().getString("Name");
        mEditText2 = intent.getExtras().getString("Date");
    }
```

getIntent will return the intent from the activity you are coming from. You do not need to creat two intents as you did, since they will be the same.

**EDIT**

**Second Activity**

Your code is never reaching the "puts" because you navigate to another activity before. You should do that.

```
    FloatingActionButton fab2 = findViewById(R.id.fab2);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("card", true);
            intent.putExtra("Name", name);
            intent.putExtra("Date", date);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Also some hints for your code.

Instead of

```
if (pressed != false)
// This means pressed is true.
```

use

```
if (pressed)
// This also means pressed is true.
```

Comment: I did that and now i get this error again:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.myuserwithoutme.birthdayremember.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74), although it says in the other activity Intent strings = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                strings.putExtra("Name", name);
                strings.putExtra("Date", date);
                strings.putExtra("card", true);
                startActivity(strings);

Comment: Now I saw your other activity, change it as I edited my code.

Comment: i dont know why, but there is still the null object reference

Comment: So, when you go from one activity A to another activity B (as you are doing) you can create just ONE intent, put the extras you want in this single intent and then after you added all of your extras you navigate to activity B by executing startActivity(). This method needs to be the last thing you will do in activity A, because once you do that you will be navigated to activity B and the rest of the code in activity A will not be executed.

Comment: About the NullPointerException, this happens when you try to do some thing in a null object, for example you have an intent that is null and you are trying to get something from this intent. For example: intent.getExtras().getString("name"), is the same than, null.getExtras().getString("name"), this will not work because you can not call this method in a null variable, that is why you receive this warning and that is why you check: if (intent != null) before getting the extras.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick edit for people that have the same problem, the startActivityForResult didnt worked at first because i had an outdated version, i updated jdk and android studio to the newest version and it worked. Thanks everybody :D